# IntelliJ "extracting project structure from sbt"

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Okay. So i ahve this problem concerning itelliJ revolving around SBT and Scala.

The problem is that intelliJ cannot correctly import the project, and i am left with an intelliJ that recognizes only false syntax errors and which cant compile from the "run" bottom integrated within the IDEA.

When I start IntelliJ/Open the project, the SBT goes to work and tries to index the project, after which it fails, returning me multiple errors.

```
Extracting structure failed: Structure file /tmp/sbt-structure.xml is empty
```

[Picture of additional erros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXjGp.png)

The thing is, that the code works, using the terminal it can both compile and run!

I feel like i have traversed the internet and done multiple things including:

**Reload SBT.**

**Try to Import the project with SBT.**

**Reinstall plugins.**

**Restart and invalidate cahces.**

Thanks in advance!